# pending add image asp.net mvc 5 visual studio

Tags: html, css

I get a "Pending add" message when I hover over the "+" sign in front of an image (whether in .png, .gif, or .jpg format) that I've just added to a project. Even though Visual Studio shows a thumbnail of the image when I hover over its name in the Solution Explorer, it is not showing up as the background of the body of my page. (When I alternately assign a background color in that same body section, that color DOES show up.) Don't know why it would matter, but I added this image by right-clicking my new Images folder and adding an existing item.

I've already gone through answers involving Pending changes, and none of those are helpful here. Any suggestions for getting this image to stop "Pending add" and be added already, so that it will render, please? Thank you.

Comment: Source control has nothing to do with HTTP.  What path are you referencing? What do you see in the Network tab?

Comment: SLaks: I'm using css: url("diagram.png"). Is this your question? I don't understand your first sentence. I never mentioned source control or HTTP.

Comment: The `Pending Add` message & Plus icon are about source control, and have nothing to do with your problem.  You're probably using the wrong relative path.

Comment: Thanks SLaks for your time and attention. I see your point about source control having nothing to do with the problem. Anyway, I wound up abandoning that version and pulling a newer one. Maybe I was a bit more careful in the coding? The image shows now.

Answer (score 3):

Commit your changes, that's all.

---

In other words, the icons on the left are the status of source control. So, it is saying that this is a new item that you added into the project. So, you now need to add it to the source control.

When you do your commit, it will detect the new file and you will have option of adding it at that time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the image was excluded you would have to include it to be shown. As you figured out, this doesn't mean it's not included in project.

The "Pending add" info indicates that it's not yet "Checked in" (when sharing a project).

If someone gets confused with this, it's probably the usage of wrong path or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I deleted the image files from Solution Explorer and re-added them, and the images were immediately checked in.